# Mysql - Order by two price columns as one

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a product table like this:

```
   id  | name     | price |discount| discount_price
    1  | Product 1| 100   | 0      |
    2  | Product 2| 150   | 1      | 75
    3  | Product 3| 200   | 1      | 80
```

I want to make an increasing filter by price.But when I want to sort by price, I can only do one column.

Without a discounted price column, there is no correct order.

I need to get results like this(for increasing price):

```
   id  | name     | price |discount| discount_price
    2  | Product 2| 150   | 1      | 75
    3  | Product 3| 200   | 1      | 80
    1  | Product 1| 100   | 0      |
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do

```
select
    id,
    name,
    price,
    discount,
    discount_price
from
    table
order by
    (case
        when discount_price = '' then  CAST(price as INT)
        else CAST(discount_price as INT)
    end);
```